# How to do FragmentStatePagerAdapter changes dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am implementing a little image gallery with ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter (I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter cause I am supporting android 2.3, so low memory devices have to be compatible too).

Since I get the images from a webservice (in an AsyncTask), I place an example image in all the fragments of the gallery until the images from the webservices are fully downloaded.

My question is, how do I change the example image in the visible fragment with one of the downloaded images? I guess I have to do something in the onPostExecute() inside the AsyncTask, capturing the visible fragment in this moment and changing the drawable in the ImageView, but I am not truly sure about how to do it. All advices are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your `Fragment` to an event bus like [`Otto`](https://square.github.io/otto), and pass the `File` location where the picture is stored to the subscribed `Fragment` (i.e. probably from `onPostExecute()`. Then you can update your `Fragment`'s UI.

Comment: Your idea look pretty complicated to me, so I finally used an easiest approach; I recreated the adapter with the downloaded images in the onPostExecute() method. TY for your comment anyway :)